# Continuity of random variable as function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Suppose, we are given a continuos random variable $X$ and a continuous and nondecreasing function $f$.

Can it be shown that a second random variable $Y=f(X)$ is continuos on the support of $X$?

What can we say about $E[f(X)]$? Is there something like continuity of $E[f(X)]$. So, assume $X$ is a uniformly distributed random variable with support $[a,b]$. Could we say that $E[f(X)]$ is continuos in the support of $X$? So, if we slightly increase $[a,b]$ to $[a,b+\epsilon]$, will also $E[f(X)]$ increase only slightly? Is there such a kind of continuity?

Does this question make sense?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Two thoughts:  (1) What is a "continuous random variable"? (2) What if $f=0$? Then $Y=0$.  Does this satisfy your definition of "continuous random variable"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 
1)By a continuous random variable, I mean a random variable with a continuos pdf. So, in my case, I always consider uniform distributions with some specific support $[a,b]$.
2) Good point: In my case, I think it would satisfy my definition.

Comment: Do you really mean "continuous CDF"?  Anyway, the random variable $Y=0$ has neither a continuous CDF (step function) nor a continuous PDF (impulse function).

Comment: The value $E[f(X)]$ is just a number, it does not make sense to talk about it being "continuous."  Perhaps you mean continuity of the expression $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^{b}f(x)dx$ with respect to $b$?

Comment: I guess, I am myself not absolutely convinced. Maybe you can point me to the proper terminology. So what I am trying to understand is, if I have a random variable $X$ that has a uniform distribution (e.g. with support $[0.5, 0.9]$), and I have some continuos function (e.g. $y=2*x$), will $f(X)$ be a continuos, in the sense, could there be some kind of jumps in the distribution of the resulting random variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you do not like the continuous function $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, then you might like this continuous function: $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
.6 & \mbox{ if $x < .6$} \\
x &\mbox{ if $x \in [.6, .7]$} \\
.7 & \mbox{ if $x>.7$}\\ 
\end{array}
\right.$$ Do you agree that if $X$ is uniform over $[.5,.9]$, then $Y=f(X)$ has a point mass at $Y=.6$?

Comment: mmmm.. so the function is continuos, but not differentiable, right?

Comment: I am not really sure, I can clearly define my problem. :( Maybe I could explain in a chat here and eventually re-post it again precisely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35478/discussion-between-michael-and-frank-merzen).